# Can't get json from weather api. iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

This is the json:

```
{ 
"main":{  
  "temp":-11.67,
  "pressure":1040.21,
  "humidity":73,
  "temp_min":-11.67,
  "temp_max":-11.67,
  "sea_level":1055.37,
  "grnd_level":1040.21
},
"id":3099213,
"name":"London",
"cod":200
}
```

I've got JSON file and I want to take the value of `"name": "London" (London)` and save it in the variable cityName, but it doesn't work there is error in line `self.cityName = city`.  Cannot assign value of type `[String : AnyObject]` to type `String!`

For example next one that have to save to variable degree temperature from JSON work correct and show temperature.

I don't know how to pick this `"name":"London"` value and save it to variable.
When I modify and put this: `self.cityName = city as! String`

I've got warning  Cast from `'[String : AnyObject]'` to unrelated type `'String'` always fails:

```
var cityName: String!

let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]


                if let main = json["main"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    if let temp = main["temp"] as? Int {
                        self.degree = temp
                    }
                }
                if let city = json["name"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    self.cityName = city
                }
}
```

Comment: `{
 "weather":[  
      {  
         "id":701,
         "main":"Mist",
         "description":"mist",
         "icon":"50n"
      }
}
////////////////////////////////////
 if let weather = json["weather"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        if let someWeather = weather["main"] as? String {
                            self.weatherDescription = someWeather
                        }
                    }`

How to save to variable weatherDescription the value of "main" or "description" from json?
I try like in this code, but it doesn't show me anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if let city = json["name"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
       self.cityName = city
  }
```

Replace to

```
 if let city = json["name"] as? String {
       self.cityName = city
  }
```

Comment: `{
 "weather":[  
      {  
         "id":701,
         "main":"Mist",
         "description":"mist",
         "icon":"50n"
      }
}
////////////////////////////////////
 if let weather = json["weather"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        if let someWeather = weather["main"] as? String {
                            self.weatherDescription = someWeather
                        }
                    }`

How to save to variable weatherDescription the value of "main" or "description" from json?
I try like in this code, but it doesn't show me anything

Comment: Please, post another question, it's extremely hard to understand Json format in comments without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're attempting to assign `cityName` which is of type `String` with `city` which is of type `[String:AnyObject]`. Cast to `String` instead before assigning to `cityName` like this:

```
var cityName: String!

let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : Any]

if let main = json["main"] as? [String : Any],
    let temp = main["temp"] as? Int {
    self.degree = temp
}

if let city = json["name"] as? String {
    self.cityName = city
}
```

Note that I've additionally replaced `[String : AnyObject]` with `[String : Any]` which is the the Swift standard for string-basd key-value dictionary objects of "any" value type. I've also removed redundant `if let` nesting by unwrapping multiple values in one conditional using `,` between statements.